# Windows10pro how to disable Services and Autostart for users

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to disable services and/or autostart for specific local users - not for all users?

Comment: Windows (from Windows NT forward) can start services without logging on. These services cannot be attributed to a specific user. You would need to see if a service you wish to disable was initiated by a specific user.  Also determine why you need to do this because disabling services is not usually necessary

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and rather simple:

- For the specified user
  [assign a user logon script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789190(v%3Dws.11)#how-to-assign-user-logon-scripts)
- Populate the script with
  [net stop](https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html)
  commands for the system services that you want to be stopped for this user.

I suggest being careful and selective when choosing these services.